# I am trying to get the length of the text added and getting the error as Uncaught TypeError

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to get the length of the state which I have defined in the validation component in `app.js` but I am encountering an error:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './App.css';
import Person from './Person/Person.js'
import Validation from './Validation/Validation.js'

class App extends Component {

  state={
    userInput:'' 
  }
render(){
return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>I am still waiting!!</h1>
        <button onClick={this.togglePersonHandler}>Toggle Button </button>
       {persons}
       <input type="text" onChange={this.inputChanged} value={this.state.userInput}/>
       <p>{this.state.userInput}</p>

       <Validation inputLength={this.state.userInput.length}/>


      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined "

Comment: Hi, were you able to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in `onChange={e=>this.inputChanged(e.target.value)}` instead of simply passing through the function. And also please share the error message?

Comment: he put the error message in the title. by the way: why would you only pass the value? In most cases you need more than just the value, so it's preferable to pass the whole event obj. (or if you don't pass any values like he does, you could leave it as he did)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but I would say you defined your state wrong. the constructor and define your state so it is accessible under "this.state" like this:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {};
}
```

so this would look kinda like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Person from './Person/Person.js'
import Validation from './Validation/Validation.js'

class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
    this.state = {
        userInput: ""
    };
}
render(){
return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>I am still waiting!!</h1>
        <button onClick={this.togglePersonHandler}>Toggle Button </button>
       {persons}
       <input type="text" onChange={this.inputChanged} value={this.state.userInput}/>
       <p>{this.state.userInput}</p>

       <Validation inputLength={this.state.userInput.length}/>


      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Another thing you can do (to prevent a crash of the application) is to check if "userInput" is not null, before trying to access a property like this. So instead of doing  this: `this.state.userInput.length` you would do something like this: `this.state.userInput && this.state.userInput.length`. the "&&" operator basically only lets the application proceed if the first value is not null / undefined / 0 / "" etc. so that way it won't crash.

This would probably not fix your issue though, but it's better than displaying a blank white page to the user.